# IntelliJ "Debug info unavailable" - how to fix?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a Java Tomcat web application built in IntelliJ that calls code in another module called "Stuff".  I've attached the source of the relevant code to "Stuff" so I can step into it and hit breakpoints, but I cannot see variables or their values.  Watches don't work either.  All I get is "Debug info unavailable".

How do I see the debug info?

Comment: Hey dude no source code is visible. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313922/step-through-jdk-source-code-in-intellij-idea). Make sure the classes are compiled with the debug info. It can be tuned in Settings | Compiler or if you build from Ant, you need debug=on attribute for the javac task.

Comment: Thanks, it was the Ant task configuration.  For those wondering exactly how to do this, add    debug="on"    to the javac node in your ant build configuration file.

Answer (score 4):

Please compile using the following options:

```
javac -g:source,lines,vars
```