# Why boolean has changed to int when debug?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, decompiler

I was debugging `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#acquireQueued` method. And I found that the `interrupted` and `failed` variables' type changed to `int` in the debugger. Here is the screenshot.
[image]

**Why does this happen?**

**Is there anything wrong in my compiler?**

I tried to decompile another class but things were ok.

[image]

My IDEA version is
`IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021`

Comment: Well that's quite strange. Perhaps an IDE issue? What version of IntelliJ are you using? Is there an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this issue you can provide for others to run?

Comment: 0 is false in boolean logic. Could just be a ide display issue.

Comment: @markfila I tried to evaluate expression in debugger, and it says that `failed` is not a boolean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ "Debug info unavailable" - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539282/intellij-debug-info-unavailable-how-to-fix)

Comment: Note the comment in your debugger above the variables: "Variables debug info not available". This is a recent issue in either Java or IntelliJ 2021.2.

Answer (score 1):

Because JVM.

Java-the-language has booleans. The JVM (Java-the-bytecode, Java-the-bytecode-runner) mostly doesn't. There are ways to convey that e.g. a method's return type is `boolean`, so booleans exist when describing the signatures of things, but the runtime model **does not have them**. For example, if we look at the [full list of all bytecode instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_bytecode_instructions) and we scan for e.g. the `xLOAD` instruction, there's:

- `aload`, which loads references
- `dload` which loads doubles
- `fload` which loads floats
- `iload` which loads ints
- `lload` which loads longs

That's it. There is no `bload` or `zload` to load a boolean, because they don't exist. They *do* exist when loading off of arrays. This makes some sense: You wouldn't want a `new byte[100]` to take up 400 bytes of memory because each byte has to be as large as an int. However, for a single field or local variable, the amount of CPU time you'd waste trying to cajole the CPU, which is fundamentally a 64-bit based concept, into working on chunks of a word, vastly exceeds any gain you'd have by being 'efficient' with your locals. So, just a local var `boolean b;` takes 64 bits, even though it could have fit in just 1.

The various auto-generated notes in the code added by the debugger refer to all this. At the bytecode level, **Local variables do not exist either** - instead, there are 'slots' and `javac` is free to reuse. For example, this code:

```
void foo() {
  int x = 5;
  System.out.println(x);
  int y = 10;
  System.out.println(y);
}
```

will compile down to **just one slot** (given that x is no longer used when you declare y, why not reuse the slot?), or possibly even zero slots as these can just be translated to an ICONST instruction + an invoke.

That's what `Slot_5` is all about.

What does a 'slot' hold? well, a reference, an int, a long, a float, or a double. That's it. It cannot hold booleans, shorts, bytes, or chars, because those do not exist. `javac` rewrites boolean logic to 0/1-based int logic.

And the debugger is just following along with that. Possibly the debugger is a bit 'lost', it's job is to translate what the bytecode is doing back to track as close as possible with the source it has.

There's certainly nothing wrong with your compiler. I doubt there's anything "wrong" with your debugger, other than that it simply isn't as advanced as it could be.

Comment: Per the last line, I think this would more likely be an issue with a (recent or ancient) copy of IntelliJ, as it has translated the boolean values correctly in the debugger display for about as long as I've used it (since 2013 for IntelliJ).