# Are debug enabled/compiled versions of the java class libraries still available

Tags: java, debugging

Background:
I'm trying to debug a problem with a swing application where I get a class cast exception in the standard boolean table renderer of JTable. I have the source code attached but don't see any of the values for the local variables or parameters. I assume this is because I'm not java libraries compiled with debug information turned on. I'm using eclipse on windows vista.

Things I've tried:
I've searched via google and on the oracle download site. There doesn't appear to be any obvious link to download a debug version of the libraries. There is one question on this site which links to an old java download site but this just redirects to the standard oracle one now.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313922/step-through-jdk-source-code-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into this problem before. There are lots of debates about it but no real answer. You will find some stale links to some early-access beta versions of JDK6 that supposedly contain a DEBUG bundle with rt.jar compiled with local variables enabled, but I have never actually found anything.

Sorry, but re-compiling it yourself seems the only option for now.

**Edit:** There appears to be some progress on this. As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288370/how-to-debug-class-files-in-eclipse/5288481#5288481) suggest, you can download the latest snapshot release which should have all jars compiled with relevant debugging info.

Comment: @rodion... please help in the steps to do the re-compile the source code without g:none option...so that i can able to see the execution in jdk files