# How can I set a breakpoint in java core class in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am using the eclipse3.4.6 and I have attached the src.zip to eclipse. I can successfully view the source code eclipse, but the breakpoint set in java core class dosn't work;
for example.

```
HashMap test = new HashMap();
test.put("a", 0);
```

I can't step into  test.put("a", 0) even if I set a breakpoint in HashMap.class at the begenning of 'put' method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made a simple test running a simple Java app in debug mode with JDK 1.6.0_27 and Eclipse 3.7.1 and it just works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you are using JDK not JRE in build path of your project.

Comment: I acttually used JRE in build path,but how can I use JDK in build path of my project.

Comment: @goddyang rightclick on the project->Properties->Java Build Oath->Libraries->Remove JDK->Add Library->JRE System Library->Choose your JDK

Comment: It works.Thanks a lot.What's the difference between these two conditions? Should I google with key words 'jdk jre buildpath'?

Comment: JDK compiled classes located inside rt.jar are compiled with debug info. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288370/how-to-debug-class-files-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be setting a "line breakpoint" which Eclipse isn't able to map to the right line possible because the source you are looking at is not exactly the same as that of the class that is running.

Try setting a "method breakpoint" instead. Open the `HashMap` class and in the **Outline** view, right click the `put` method and select **Toggle Method Breakpoint**.

Comment: You mean the source code can't match the .class file?Wojtek O. has fiexd the problem. Thank you all the same, and I learn the 'method breakpoint' ^_^