# How to debug in-case only class files are present in form of Jar files

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on an existing application where I am provided with some java files and a lot of jar files.
I have imported this Application into Eclipse where I'm able to build the project.

Now, I need to debug some of the `.class` files inside the jar files using Eclipse Debugger.
(For which I don't have the `.java` files for them)

Please let me know, how can we put Debug Points to debug in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288370/how-to-debug-class-files-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a decompiler plugin for your IDE. (for example JADclipse: http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) This way, when you click on a linked file from a library eclipse will try to use JAD to decompile the file present in the jar-file.

Please be advised that decompiling is not 100% bulletproof, so line numbers are not always correct.