# not able to debug on eclipse class files: just started facing this issue

Tags: java, debugging

facing the issue while debugging 
[image: eclipse screen shot]
"String.hashCode() line: not available"

i have refereed this , [How to debug .class files in ECLIPSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288370/how-to-debug-class-files-in-eclipse)   but this talks of debug build, but i want to know what is wrong with my existing system

@ siegi I have done these changes and not able to modify the highlighted(blue) par to point to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib\rt.jar

[image: implementing the changes]

one more problem:
String.hashCode() line: 1489 [local variables unavailable]

[image: eclipse debug snapshot]

Comment: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-view-and-debug-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse.html?page=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using the class files from the JRE. I guess they are compiled without the [`LineNumberTable` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12). You can try to run your application with JDKs JRE (if I remember correctly on Windows the path should be something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk6\jre`).

Comment: thanks...but it did not work....C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre........................as i searched on internet the other option which seems available is recompile the src.zip...but i don know to do it without using -g:none....

Comment: @jain007 I don't think this should be necessary. Are you sure the JDK JRE is also used in your project? Please check this by looking at the paths in the "JRE System Library" entry in your project. Eclipse often needs some reloading or manual updating after playing around with the global JRE configuration. After checking that, is it still the same "line: not available" problem?

Comment: added one more screenshot......done the changes to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre.........but not able to point the rt.jar to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre\lib

Comment: @jain007 In the "Installed JREs" page try to remove all listed JREs and click on "Search…". It should find at least the JDK JRE. Click the checkbox in front of it to make it the default and restart your Eclipse. Does this help? Maybe you also need to update the defaults in the "Execution Environments" preferences page.

Comment: huh.....wow....thanks for the help and extended support to make it work..you rock in th way you give personal support

Comment: one more doubt..now ..not able to inspect the values

Comment: @jain007 Sorry, I'm not sure here, maybe it's better if you start a new question so others can help you here...