# How to watch variables when tracing over JRE in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, java, watch

I found that when tracing **JRE source code** in eclipse, I can't see variable values. Is it possible to see them somehow?

**EDIT**

The answer was to rebuild `rt.jar`. Just attaching JDK sources is not sufficient.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313922/step-through-jdk-source-code-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean debugging java code ? if so if you set a breakpoint a debugger should stop there and you are going to see all variables in a current context. You can even mouseover your source code to see values

Comment: Not if the class has been compiled without debug information. This is the OPs issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try [how-do-i-view-and-debug-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-view-and-debug-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse.html)