# debugging not able to inspect the variables

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

while debugging in eclipse
the problem is: String.hashCode() line: 1489 [local variables unavailable]
thus, not able to inspect the values of variables
[image: ECLIPSE debug screenshot]

please help me on this by providing some pointers

**Hi Tomasz Nurkiewicz**
Thanks for the efforts, i took a new jdk (haing all the class details) after catching on these [How to debug .class files in ECLIPSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288370/how-to-debug-class-files-in-eclipse) and http://jdk6.java.net/download.html but then also facing same issue................
[image: eclipse debug image after changes]

Comment: solution is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271521/locally-declared-variables-can-not-be-inspected/12911067#12911067

Answer (score 5):

JDK classes aren't compiled with debugging information, hence you can't see local variables during debugging. You'll have to rebuild JDK or use development version, see: [Step through JDK source code in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313922) and [Enabling debugging inside JRE classes](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t103334.html).

Comment: i am using eclipse and dont want to use IntelliJ...and the second link takes me to work on cmd prompt which i tried..but i am not good on this

Comment: @jain007: the first link "*is not specific to IntelliJ IDEA.*"; unfortunately you'll probably need to work a little bit with command line.

Comment: ok...just help me run this cmd .....\unxutils\usr\local\wbin\find.exe -name *.java > files.txt .....mine jdk is at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31......i am not able to understand that where this find.exe utility exists...even though some ref is given in http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t103334.html

Comment: I think some problems with debugging appears after Java 8. Who knows is it true or not?